# How to test, if an element is in a list?

Tags: rexx

Is there a built-in function to test, if a given element is in a list in Rexx?

I could not find one. The alternative would be to loop over the list and check each element manually.

Comment: What sort of list are talking about? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No (unless things have changed); just loop through the list.

An alternative is instead / as well have a lookup variable

i.e.

```
lookup. = 0  /* not all versions of Rexx support 
                default initialisation like this */

      ....

addToList:
parse arg item
    numberInList = numberInList + 1
    list.numberInList = item
    lookup.item = 1
return
```

You can then check if item is in the list by

```
if lookup.item = 1 then do
    ......
```

Comment: An version of Rexx that doesn't support `x. = y` is seriously broken.  But +1 anyway, this is one of the usual techniques.

Comment: 8 or 9 years ago some of the PC rexx interpreters did not support the x.= syntax, I caught out once, I found I could get around the issue by explicitly testing lookup.item = 1 or lookup.item = yes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by a list.

At work, I use classic REXX.  I frequently store lists of words in a single variable, space delimited.  So WORDPOS() is the built-in function I use.

If you are using a [List](http://www.oorexx.org/docs/rexxref/x12261.htm#CLSLIST) class in ooREXX. then why not use the [hasItem](http://www.oorexx.org/docs/rexxref/x12261.htm#MTHCOLLECTIONHASITEM) method from the Collection class.